# java how to get json from a request?

Tags: jsp, servlets, struts2

I'm posting a json request to server. I can see the http post is done correctly in firebug. (I'm sure the json format is valid)

eg.  {datas:[{"a":1, "b":2},{"a":5, "b":6}]}

my question is, how do I recover this data in the server side? I read people saying to use `request.getInputStream` but can't figure how to convert it into string or parse with GSON.

another question: is there a limite of size of a json string I can post?

(Struts 2)

```
dojo.xhrPost({
                url: "sub/sub/theAction",
                postData: dojo.toJson(json),
                handleAs:'json',
                headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"},          
                load: function(data) {      
                    alert("done");          

                        }
                }                       
            });
```

thanks in advance

Comment: how you posting data to server side??

Comment: hi, I just updated the question, now with how am I posting data

Comment: :can you show how you have configured action in configuration file?

Comment: actually it's just a empty action, I mean I just maped to a method which only has a "println" for testing <action name="theAction" class="mx.com.testing" method="theAction">

Comment: use the plugin what Dave has said and i have provided an example for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am not sure how DOJO works or post data but believe must be same as other javascript framework works.
here is what we can do to achieve what you are trying to do

```
<package name="demojson" extends="struts-default,json-default">
    <action name="jsonTest" class="com.demo.action.JsonTestAction">
        <interceptor-ref name="json">
            <param name="contentType">application/json</param>
        </interceptor-ref>
        <result type="json"/>
    </action>
</package>

public class JsonTestAction extends ActionSupport
{
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private Map data = new HashMap();
        // log decelaration         
        public Map getData()
        {
                return data;
        }

        public void setData(Map data)
        {
                this.data = data;
        }

        @Override
        public String execute()
        {
                logger.log(Level.FINE, "action parameters: " + data);

                return SUCCESS;
        }
}


var submit = function()
{
    var data = {data: {j1 : 'one', j2: 'two', j3: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], j4: {a: 'A', b: 2, c: '3'}, j5: 2, j6: '2'}};
    jQuery.ajax(
    {
        type: 'POST', 
        url: '/blah/jsonTest.action', 
        data: jQuery.toJSON(data),
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false ,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: do what you want here}
    });
```

how json works with Struts2 refer this

[JSON Plugin for Struts2](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/JSON%20Plugin)
};

hope this will help you

Comment: thank you very much, I got my problem solved :D the interceptor is what I was missing

Comment: sorry, but now when I call the jsonTest.action the HttpServletRequest object in that action is null :S, I implement the ServletRequestAware interface, other methods in the same action are working fine

Comment: nvm, I used (HttpServletRequest) ActionContext.getContext().get(ServletActionContext.HTTP_REQUEST); instead and worked thanks

Comment: @Kossel:Why you are using HttpServletRequest since the request parameters will be passed by the framework itself using params interceptor.try to avoid coupling of Servlet API with your action.

Comment: Because I use it to get the ApplicationContext for Spring to find and have services classes injected. :/

Comment: @Kossel: why don't you use struts2- spring plugin as it will work out of the box to inject action/services http://struts.apache.org/2.0.8/docs/spring-plugin.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the [JSON Plugin](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/JSON%20Plugin) along with its interceptor; the Struts 2 action will be populated using the request data.

Note the requirements for the JSON on the plugin docs page.